# Extract the elements after the regex in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

I have a column in dataframe whose data is as below. Now I need only the elements after test1

i.e It should return abc,efg,ghg , and also the length varies for each row.

```
 test1:abc,test2:ghr,test2:jkl,test1:efg,test3:erp dfg (jfg),test1:ghg
```

I am trying to write a method to return on the parts after test1, I tried as below.
But it wont work exactly what I intended to achieve.Please let me know if there is a way to achieve it

```
def findStr(str:String):Array[String]= {
  if (str.contains ("test1:") ) {
  val res = test.split ("test1:")
 for (i <- res.length - 1) {
  val res1 = res (i)
 if (res1.contains (",") ) {
   val res2 = res1.split (",")(0)
    }
  else null
  }
 else null
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this:

```
val input = " test1:abc,test2:ghr,test2:jkl,test1:efg,test3:erp dfg (jfg),test1:ghg"

input
  .split(",")
  // Array(" test1:abc", test2:ghr, test2:jkl, test1:efg, test3:erp dfg (jfg), test1:ghg)
  .map(_.split(":"))
  // Array(Array(" test1", abc), Array(test2, ghr), Array(test2, jkl), Array(test1, efg), Array(test3, erp dfg (jfg)), Array(test1, ghg))
  .filter{ case Array(k, v) => k.trim == "test1" }
  // Array(Array(" test1", abc), Array(test1, efg), Array(test1, ghg))
  .map{ case Array(k, v) => v }
  // Array(abc, efg, ghg)
  .mkString(",")
  // "abc,efg,ghg"
```

This solution assumes the input string follows this format:

```
key1:valueA,key2:valueB:key1:valueC,...
```

Instead of splitting on `test1`, since you have a structure of key values delimited by `","`, you can split on ",".

This gives you a sequence of key/value strings, which gives you an easy way to deal individually with keys which are "test1".

I think you went for a recursive function, where you split on test1, which gives you the value directly after test1, and you would be able to call your function again with the left part of the split in order to find the next "test1", and so on. But I think it's a little overkill in this case.

As a side note, I would suggest not to use `null` in Scala and instead use the [Option monad](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Option.html).